# Traveling with expired permesso di soggiorno and valid passport

Tags: schengen, paperwork, italy, residency, land-borders

Can I cross Schengen borders with an expired permesso di soggiorno
and poste renewal receipts with a valid non-EU passport ?

Comment: I wonder if this might be better on Expats? As it's about expired residency cards, which is an expats things

Comment: I have searched almost everything on internet
But still not get an satisfying answer and i have to travel for some important reason as soon as possible and renewal of permesso di soggiorno would take long time

Comment: Can you be more specific (which country do you need to visit)?